# wget visit url which has parent directory exactly after the hostname

Tags: wget

**Update: I upgrade wget from 1.10 to 1.12 and solved the problem.**

For example

> www.example.com/level1/level2/../test.html

In this way, wget and browser will visit

> www.example.com/level1/test.html

But for

> www.example.com/../test.html

wget will visit

> www.example.com/../test.html

browser will visit

> www.example.com/test.html

I was using wget to parse some webpage to get the size of it and the elements inside it.
Now I found that some webpage are using "../css/xxx.jpg" instead of "css/xxx.jpg".
It is Ok to visit the webpage with browser, but not wget.

Is there a way to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Before passing URLs to wget, trim "../" from the begging of the path. (splitting the URLS into components would help.)

How to do this depends on what language or framework you are using.

Comment: The urls are inside the html file and wget parse them automatically, so I have no way to deal with it. Now wget 1.12 can do it rightly.